# PayPal emails go to Spam folder on Mail Mac

Tags: mail.app, paypal

I use Mac Mail as my email program and I would like to know why PayPal emails go always to the spam folder. I have tried to make rules, mark PayPal email as VIP contact but nothing works.

I would like them to be sent to my primary inbox.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but are you *sure* they're PayPal emails?  PayPal is a popular phishing target.

Comment: Is it mail marking yen as spam or is it your mail provider?

Comment: Yes, it is legit. They are just invoices for things I have paid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E-mails that have been placed into the spam folder by Apple Mail will have this header: [image]

If you see an e-mail in your spam folder that lacks this header, than the e-mail has been automatically been placed into the spam folder by your mail provider. You should mark it as "not spam" from within your mail service's web client.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these mails are really from Paypal, you can retrain the spam filter by marking them as "not spam" in the Spam folder and then moving them to your Inbox again. It may take some time to change the current rules though.